# Cannot access public methods in extended Javascript class - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing this issue while accessing public methods of an extended class.

[image: public method in newborn instance is not a function]

This is the code of my connect(), it seems nothing wrong in it, i don't get why i can't use it from outside.

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, setPersistence, browserLocalPersistence, getIdToken, updateProfile, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';

export default class AuthManager extends getAuth {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  async connect() {
   // do something 
  }
}
```

This is instead how i declare the instance outside

```
import AuthManager from './auth/firebase-auth';

export default class FirebaseManager {
  #config = void 0;
  constructor(config) {
    this.isValidConfig(config)
      ? (this.#_initConfig = config)
      : () => {throw new TypeError('Missing or invalid configuration for FirebaseManager')}
  }
  set #_initConfig(conf) {
    this.#config = conf;
    this.#initiate();
  }
  isValidConfig(config) { // bla bla }
  async #initiate() {
    this.authenticationManager = new AuthManager(); <----- HERE
    await this.authenticationManager.connect() <----- connect() is not a function
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

[I tried instead to assign the function to a member and it works that way, but i didn't mean to use this that way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpPtP.png)

I also tried to define privately the function and it works fine, if i call it directly from the class.

```
  async #connect() {
   // do something 
  }
}
```